Question on Theorem 2.4 from Chapter VI of Ma and Röckner
In the above mentioned theorem in the book "Introduction to the Theory of (non-symmetric) Dirichlet Forms" the one-to-one correspondence of PCAFs $A$ and smooth measures $\mu$ is expressed via the identity
$$
\lim_{t\searrow 0} E_m\biggl[\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(X_s) \, \mathrm{d}A_s\biggr] \,=\,
\int_E f\,\mathrm{d}\mu
$$
for all non-negative Borel measurable $f\colon E\to \mathbb{R}$. In other expositions of Dirichlet form theory like in Theorem 5.1.3 of the book "Dirichlet forms and symmetric Markov processes" by Fukushima, Oshima and Takeda, the correspondence requires that
$$
\lim_{t\searrow 0} E_{h\cdot m}\biggl[\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(X_s) \, \mathrm{d}A_s\biggr] \,=\,
\int_E  h\,\mathrm{d}(f\mu)
$$
for all $\gamma$-excessive funstions $h\colon E\to \mathbb{R}$, and $\gamma\ge 0$. The function $f$ is again non-negative and Borel measurable.  My question is, how does the seemingly more general second statement follow from the first one?

I think the statement of Revuz's formula in M-R's book (p.123) is the same as F-O-T?

Ah I didn't know this passage thanks a lot. It doesn't fully answer my question though; now I should rather ask about the difference between the Revuz formulas on the pages 123 and 179, where Theorem VI.2.4 is stated, of M-R's book: Namely why in the first one the expectation is taken with respect to $hm$ for an $\gamma$-excessive function $h$ and in the second one with respect to $m$? (and why this is is seemingly eqivalent)

I should add that in the proof of Theorem VI.2.4 they refer to the notes of a lecture of Oshima from '88 which he held at Erlangen-Nuremberg, which were unfortunately never published. Also, I unfortunately cannot find such statements in the the Book 'Semi-Dirichlet forms and Markov processes' of Oshima, in which I assume much of his lecture notes went in the end.
